# How to increase font using Tikz for the following dense protocol?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, tikz-styles

This figure is made with Tikz package, I need suggestions to make font more bigger and more readable. I tried many solutions such as \Large but still not able to increase the font more clear. My advisor told me to use the spaces in the image attached. Any suggestions to make the font more clear and bigger ??

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
       \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}

  \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[o-o/.style={{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}}, every  node/.append style={font=\LARGE}]

\node (A) at (-8.5,+1){};
 \node (B) at (-8.5,-15){};
\draw[-] (A)--(B);


\node (C) at (-7.1,+1){};
\node (D) at (-7.1,-15){};
\draw[-] (C)--(D);

\node (A) at (-7.8,-1.3){};
\node (B) at (-7.8,-15){};
\draw[->,green] (A)--(B);

    \node[xshift=-2.7cm] (a) {\Large\textcolor{red}{$v_1$ generate a temporary key pair list} };



  \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=4cm]a.east) --+ (4,0) node [black,midway,above=.1cm] {\Large $Mx^{1}_{v_{1}}$};


         \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=4cm]a.east) --+ (4,0) node[text width=4cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] {\Large$\mathcal{T}_{1}= M_{1} || Z_{H_{1}}$  };

  \node[right=10.6 of a,yellow!70!black, yshift=-.7cm,xshift=1.4cm] (b) 
 {\Large\textcolor{black}{$H_1$}};


         \node[right=0.01 of b] {
%\LARGE
\Large
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Generates: $M_1 = \{Mx^{1}_{v_{1}}, (t_1, Mxa_{H_{1})}\}$ \\
    Determines $\mathrm{Sh}_{H_1}(M_1)$
\end{tabular}
        };


          \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]


           \node[xshift=-2.2cm] (a) {
%\LARGE
\Large
\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
\textcolor{red}{ Run the the algorithm to get ($G_{\mathcal{T}_{1}})$} \\
 $L_{H_{1}}=(\mathcal{T}_{1}||G_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}||Mx^{2}_{v_{1}} ) || \sigma_{Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{1}, G_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}, Mx^{2}_{v_{1}})$
\end{tabular}

   };


            \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=3cm]a.east) --+ (4,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {\Large $\mathrm{L}_{H_1}$};


       \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=1.5cm]a.east) --+ (7,0) node[text width=7.5cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] {\Large $\mathcal{T}_{2}= M_{2} || Z_{H_{2}}(M_{1})|| Z_{H_{2}}(M_{2} )  $  };


       \node[right=9.4 of a,yellow!70!black, yshift=-.7cm,xshift=1.4cm] (b) {\Large\textcolor{black}{$H_2$}};






   \node[right=0.01 of b] (c) {
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{l}
     Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_1}$ and execution shares\\
     Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}$ \\

     Generates $M_{2}=\{Mx^{2}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Mxa_{H_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Mxa_{H_{2}})\}$   \\
     Determines $Z_{H_{2}}(M_{1})$ \\

     Determines $Z_{H_{2}}(M_{2})$\\
    \end{tabular}
};

  \end{scope}

  \draw[o-o,dashed] (-7,-1.8) -- (30,-1.8);




\draw[o-o,dashed] (-7,-5.6) -- (30,-5.6);


    \begin{scope}[yshift=-7.5cm]

       \node[xshift=-2.2cm] (a) {
%\LARGE
\Large
\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
\textcolor{red}{ Run the the algorithm to get ($G_{\mathcal{T}_{2}})$} \\
 $L_{H_{2}}=({\mathcal{T}_{2}||G_{\mathcal{T}_{2}}|| Mx^{3}_{v_{1}} ) || \sigma_{SK^{1}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{2},  G_{\mathcal{T}_{2}}, Mx^{3}_{v_{1}}}) $
 \end{tabular}

 };


      \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=3cm]a.east) --+ (4,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {\Large $\mathrm{L}_{H_2}$};


      \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (9,0) node[text width=9.5cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] {\Large $\mathcal{T}_{3}= {M}_{1} || \sigma({M_{1}}) || M_{3} ||Z_{H_{3}}(M_{2})  || Z_{H_{3}}(M_{3} )$};


        \node[right=9.4 of a,yellow!70!black, yshift=-.7cm,xshift=1.4cm] (b) {\Large\textcolor{black}{$H_3$}};







    \node[right=0.01 of b] (c) {
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{l}
     Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_2}$ and execution shares \\
     Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_{2}}$ \\
     Determines $Z_{H_{3}}(M_{1})$ \\
     Determines $\sigma(M_{1})$ \\
     Generates $M_{3}=\{Mx^{3}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Mxa_{H_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Mxa_{H_{2}} || (t_{3}, Mxa_{H_{3}})\}$ \\
     Determines $Z_{H_{3}}(M_{2})$\\
     Determines $Z_{H_{3}}(M_{3})$\\
    \end{tabular}
};

 \end{scope}





             \draw[o-o,dashed] (-7,-10.7) -- (30,-10.7);


     \begin{scope}[yshift=-12.5cm]


         \node[xshift=-2.2cm] (a) {
%\LARGE
\Large
\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
\textcolor{red}{ Run the the algorithm to get ($G_{\mathcal{T}_{3}}$)} \\

  $L_{H_{3}}=({\mathcal{T}_{3}||G_{\mathcal{T}_{3}}|| Mx^{4}_{v_{1}} ) || \sigma_{SK^{3}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{3}, G_{\mathcal{T}_{3}}, Mx^{4}_{v_{1}}}) $
\end{tabular}

 };







       \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=3cm]a.east) --+ (4,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {\Large $\mathrm{L}_{H_3}$};


     \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (9,0) node[text width=9.5cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] {\Large $\mathcal{T}_{4}= {M}_{2} || \sigma({M_{2}}) || M_{4}||Z_{H_{4}}(M_{3})  || Z_{H_{4}}(M_{4} )$  };






             \node[right=9.4 of a,yellow!70!black, yshift=-.7cm,xshift=1.4cm] (b) {\Large\textcolor{black}{$H_4$}};





       \node[right=0.01 of b] (c) {
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{l}
     Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_3}$ and execution shares \\
 Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_{3}}$ \\
 Determines $Z_{H_{4}}(M_{2})$ \\
 Determines $\sigma({M_{{2}}})$ \\
 Generates  $M_{4}=\{Mx^{4}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Mxa_{H_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Mxa_ {H_{2}} ) || (t_{3}, Mxa_{H_{3}} || (t_{4}, Mxa_{H_{4}})\}$ \\
 Determines $Z_{H_{4}}(M_{3})$ \\
 Determines $Z_{H_{4}}(M_{4})$\\
    \end{tabular}
          };

       \end{scope}




   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code won't compile. Apart from the fact that you include graphics that most likely none of the users has, you forgot to provide the definition of `\point` and the `o-o` style. BTW, if any of the answers you received so far helped you to solve your problems, could you perhaps consider accepting them? You could e.g. use `\begin{tikzpicture}[o-o/.style={{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}},
every node/.append style={font=\LARGE}]` and kick out all `\Large` commands to universally increase the size of the characters.

Comment: The code is working on overleaf. May be because there are figures that is not included so you are not able to run it

Comment: @marmot The code is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

- i would write your image as table.
- the largest font size, which enable to write table (or your image) into A4 page with `margins=15mm` and in the landscape orientation is `\large` if you allow to break long equation into two lines.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[landscape,margin=15mm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

  \usepackage{array, arydshln}
  \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  \begin{document}

  \begingroup
      \large
      \setlist[itemize]{nosep,label=,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{1ex},after=\vspace{-2ex}}
  \tikzset{base/.style = {text=black, inner xsep=3mm, inner ysep=2mm},
           boxA/.style = {name=A,
                          base,path picture={%
                          \draw[semithick,cyan,-{Straight Barb[length=0pt 3]}]
                          ([yshift=1mm]\ppbb.south west) -- ([yshift=1mm]\ppbb.south east);
                                          }
                          },
           boxB/.style = {base,text=black, inner xsep=2mm,
                          path picture={%
                          \draw[semithick,cyan,-{Straight Barb[length=0pt 3]}]
                          ([yshift=-1mm]\ppbb.north east) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\ppbb.north west);
                                          },
                          below=of A},
         node distance = -1mm
           }
      \centering
      \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} m{64mm} >{\centering}m{80mm} >{$}c<{$} m{94mm} @{}}
  \textcolor{red}{$v_1$ generate a temporary key pair list}
      &   \tikz[baseline]{
          \node [boxA] {$M_{x^1_{v_1}}$};
          \node [boxB] {$\mathcal{T}_1= M_1\| Z_{H_1}(M_{1})$};
                          }
          &   H_1
              &   \begin{itemize}
                  \item   Generates $M_1=\bigl\{M x^1_{v_1},(t_1,Max_{H_1}\bigr\}$
                  \item   Determine $\mathrm{Sh}_{H_1}(M_1)$
                  \end{itemize}\\
      \hdashline
  \textcolor{red}{Execute the algorithm to get $(G_{T_1})$}\newline
  $\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
  L_{H_1} = (\mathcal{T}_1 \| G_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}\| Mx^2_{v_1})\| \\
              \sigma_{Pr^1_{v_1}}(\mathcal{T}_1, G_{\mathcal{T}_1}, Mx^2_{v_1})
   \end{multlined}$
      &   \tikz[baseline]{
          \node [boxA] {$\mathrm{L}_{H_1}$};
          \node [boxB] {$\mathcal{T}_2= M_2\| Z_{H_2}(M_{1})\| Z_{H_2}(M_2)$};
                          }
          &   H_2
              &   \begin{itemize}
                  \item   Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_1}$
                  \item   Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_1}$
                  \item   Generates $M_2=\bigl\{Mx^2_{v_1} \| (t_{1}, Max_{H_{1}}) \| (t_{2}, Max_{H_{2}})\bigr\}$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_{2}}(M_{1})$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_{2}}(M_{2})$
                  \end{itemize}\\
      \hdashline
  \textcolor{red}{Execute the algorithm to get ($G_{\mathcal{T}_{2}})$} \newline
  $\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
  L_{H_2}=(\mathcal{T}_2\|G_{\mathcal{T}_2}\| Mx^3_{v_1}) \|  \\
          \sigma_{SK^1_{v_1}}(\mathcal{T}_2, G_{\mathcal{T}_2}, Mx^3_{v_1})
   \end{multlined}$
      &   \tikz[baseline]{
          \node [boxA] {$\mathrm{L}_{H_2}$};
          \node [boxB] {$\mathcal{T}_3= M_1\| \sigma(M_1)\| M_3\|
                        Z_{H_3}(M_2)\| Z_{H_3}(M_3)$};
                          }
          &   H_3
              &   \begin{itemize}
                  \item   Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_2}$ and execution
                  \item   Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_2}$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_{3}}(M_1)$
                  \item   Determine $\sigma(M_1)$
                  \item   Generates
                  $\begin{multlined}[t]
                  M_{3}=\bigl\{Mx^{3}_{v_1}\| (t_1, Max_{H_1})\|   \\
                  (t_2, Max_{H_2}\| (t_3, Max_{H_3})\bigr\}
                   \end{multlined}$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_3}(M_2)$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_3}(M_3)$
                  \end{itemize}\\
      \hdashline
  \textcolor{red}{execute the algorithm to get ($G_{\mathcal{T}_3}$)} \newline
  $\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
  L_{H_3}=(\mathcal{T}_{3}\|G_{\mathcal{T}_3}\| Mx^4_{v_1})\| \\ \sigma_{SK^3_{v_1}}(\mathcal{T}_3, G_{\mathcal{T}_3}, Mx^4_{v_1})
   \end{multlined}$
      &   \tikz[baseline]{
          \node [boxA] {$\mathrm{L}_{H_3}$};
          \node [boxB] {$\mathcal{T}_4=M_2\| \sigma(M_2)\|
                        M_4\|Z_{H_4}(M_3)\| Z_{H_4}(M_4)$};
                          }
          &   H_4
              &   \begin{itemize}
                  \item   Verifies $\mathrm{L}_{H_3}$ and execution
                  \item   Verifies $G_{\mathcal{T}_{3}}$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_{4}}(M_{2})$
                  \item   Determine $\sigma({M_{{2}}})$
                  \item   Generates
                  $\begin{multlined}[t]
                  M_4=\bigl\{Mx^4_{v_1}\|(t_1, Max_{H_1})\| \\
                      (t_2, Max_{H_2})\| (t_3, Max_{H_3})\| (t_4, Max_{H_4})\bigr\}
                   \end{multlined}$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_4}(M_3)$
                  \item   Determine $Z_{H_4}(M_4)$
                  \end{itemize}\\
  \hdashline
  \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Your solution is new and I like it. But in the my original code, I was having a 2 nodes as in the following code. I tried to add them but it gives me errors:
`\node[right=10.6 of a,yellow!70!black, yshift=-.7cm,xshift=1.4cm] (b) {\Large\textcolor{black}{$H_1$}};
  
  \node[right=8.3 of a] (b) (russell) at (4.1,0)
  {\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{Figures/R}}; `

Comment: @HebaMohsen, do you refer to your mwe? such approach as you show in  comment, is not present in my mwe ...  note, my mwe is rewritten from scratch and replicate showed image. it hasn't anything common with your mwe (which code is almost not possible to understand). if you have new request, pleas ask new question that more member of site can help you. sorry, i do not understand your comment.

Comment: Thanks.  but you forget to add the two separated  vertical lines in  my mwe, (Please see the attached picture). I am trying to add them to your mwe but I am not able. Could you please help me as I am new to tkiz?

Comment: @HebaMohsen, your image is not clear. i see there some lines on the left, but i assumed that they are some artifacts arisen at copy your image from your PC to here. can you explain where should be these lines, what they should connect? what is they purposes.  they can be part of table, but note, the any widening of the table can cause that table will spill out of page ...

Comment: I have updated the question with a clear image. The two lines represent a road of a car. The green line is the path of it. Your answer is great. what I need now, is just to add the lines to the your code.

Comment: for this addition simply is not enough place on the page. you should reduce table size and not  required to enlarge font size. with recent edition of your question you actually form new question. please, be so  kind and this last changes ask as new question, where you can use my answer (which fulfills your original question, consequently you should accept it)  and clearly explain, what you like to have. the key information is your document page layout.